# How to count total times in numpy array where first column >1 and second column is <1

Tags: numpy

I have numpy array like below I want to count total times columnsa>1 and columnsb<1

array

```
   [[1.2, 0.693],
   [1.2, 0.724],
   [0.976, 0.039],
   [0.987, 0.725],
   [0.979, 0.528],
   [0.978, 0.600],
   [0.983, 0.654],
   [0.986, 0.059],
   [0.979, 0.644],
   [0.982, 0.468]])]
```

Answer should yield 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can obtain the first column with `arr[:,0]` and the second with `arr[:,1]`. We can then make checks with `arr[:,0] > 1` and `arr[:,1] < 1`. By using an AND operator (`&`), we obtain an array where an element is `True` if and only if the two corresponding elements are `True`. Finally we can sum up the booleans to obtain the number of times this is `True`:

```
>>> ((arr[:,0] > 1) & (arr[:,1] < 1)).sum()
2
```